# Хочу перемешать слово в c++

Tags: c++

Привет,  хотел попробовать написать игру, в которой надо отгадать загаданное перемешанное слово, вопрос: как?
вот пример кода:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;
int main()
{

    string s;
    cin >> s;
    int a = s.size();
    return 0;

}
```

Ну, а дальше не знаю)

Answer (score 7):

Ответ на Ваш [вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8364597/shuffling-string) есть на английском SO:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    string str;
    cout << "Please enter a  word: "; //ask for input
    cin >> str;
    random_shuffle(str.begin(), str.end());
    cout << str << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Допустим, можно сделать текстовый файл со словами(в каждой строке по слову), считывать построчно в массив слов, затем рандомно выбрать одно из них, и рандомно перемешать в нем буквы, а затем ответ испытуемого сравнивать с эталоном.

Comment: Так я - то и хочу узнать, как перемешать слово

Comment: Тогда добрый человек выше, прекрасно ответил на ваш вопрос)